# Nucleophilic substitution in aromatic compounds

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, nucleophilic-substitution

> Predict the major product in following reaction:
>
> [image: Nucleophilic substitution in 1,4‐dichlorobenzene]

In my view this reaction will proceed via benzyne intermediate and $\ce{NH2-}$ will act as a base and substitute one of the chlorine. After benzyne formation as $\ce{Cl}$ is *ortho*/*para* directing my view was that $\ce{NH2-}$ will attach to the *meta* position.

However, the answer key says overwise. Any ideas?

Comment: Think about which species can act as electrophiles in EAS, would ammonia work?

Comment: @AS_1000 in my view $\ce{NH_2 ^{-}}$ acts as a nucleophile

Comment: Look up Meisenheimer intermediates rather than Wheland intermediates.  The former are valid for nucleophilic aromatic substitutions.

Comment: Note that halides are weak EWG's. So, para product is preferred