# Why methoxy group acts similar to trifluoromethyl in nucleophilic aromatic substitution

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

In an online test, the following question was asked:

[image]

The answer to this question was:

[image]

I totally agree with the answer, as $\ce{OCH_3}$ is an EDG, hence it will tend to form meta product in this reaction.

---

While reading [NAS](https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2018/09/17/nucleophilic-aromatic-substitution-2-benzyne/?unapproved=559702&moderation-hash=11751ee2e0e2adafb7a9f9cbeb58e4e7#comment-559702) on Master Organic Chemistry, I came up to this article:

[image]

This article says that $\ce{OCH_3}$ behaves similar to $\ce{CF_3}$, but I can't figure out the possible reason. Any help is appreciated!

---

Related (unanswered) question: [Nucleophilic substitution in aromatic compounds](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/84998/nucleophilic-substitution-in-aromatic-compounds)

Comment: 1) although the use here is technically correct, usually "nucleophilic aromatic substitution" refers to SNAr mechanism. 2) for a benzyne mechanism, resonance effects do not matter, only inductive. This is covered in typical organic chemistry textbooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally during a nucleophillic aromatic substitution reaction one of oxygen's lone pairs would delocalize across the ring, the existence of a triple bond here prevents this from happening so oxygen actually ends up acting like an EWG.